# Asymmetric decryption through LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, encryption

I've got a column in a table that has been asymmetrically encrypted through a SQL trigger. The key (by password) resides in the SQL DB. Now, I need to decrypt it through a console app running every xx minutes.

I'm grabbing all the fields through LINQ and running a foreach loop and generating some text files and xml files and so forth. The issue arises when I try to decrypt the data.

So, I've got a few options, but none are getting me anywhere.

- I've tried to run an ExecuteCommand, but I haven't been able to resolve how to open the asymmetric key in the first place.
- I've tried running a stored procedure, then calling it through LINQ. But can I loop through the results in order to match them (i.e., should I be running a foreach inside of the foreach)?
- I've tried 12 different other things, to no avail. :)

Anyway, any thoughts would be much appreciated. I just need to grab the unencrypted values (I'm able to decrypt them just fine in MSSQL) and add them to my workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use a View, and binding a new Linq Entity to that; that's assuming you have the SQL to decrypt the values.  This way, you can prevent round-trips to the server and just have it present you with a window over the decrypted table values.

But if you want to be able to update the table through the same entities; then you couldn't.  You'd have to make the changes through the table mapping - using the IDs to select the correct entities to be updated.

Comment: Actually, I ended up figuring out a way to do it via ExecuteCommand! And I run it to match the ID that's included in the foreach loop... so it will match. The query works great, it seems. Now my next question is... (and this is too simple, but I have a case of the fried brains at this point):

How do I return the string value of the results from ExecuteCommand? I know it will be a just one field.